# Injecting Cucumber Scenario using Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have a bean in which I need to inject a Cucumber Scenario. Is there any possible way to do this?
Bellow is an example of what I'm trying to achive:

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverConfig {

    @Bean
     public WebDriver getWebDriver(DriverUtil driverUtil, Scenario scenario) {
         return driverUtil.getDriver(scenario);
     }
 }
```

Comment: What's your goal. This doesn't make much sense to me to inject a `Scenario`: they are a runtime object built by Cucumber, not something that can be injected.

Comment: Hi @Gaël J, I create a remote connection to Selenium Box and I need the test name to configure it (so it's a remote web driver). Unfortunatly, it's a requirement

Comment: Can't you use `Before` hooks?

Comment: I need the WebDriver instance for other configurations like PageObjects instantiation and some method wrappers that perform Selenium Actions